# ExtJs 6 doSort method

Tags: sorting, extjs

I didn't find doSort function available in EXT 6 with respect to the grid columns and also didnt find it in any upgrade notes. may be because it is a private function, can anyone please tell me what is the alternative to do the same thing what doSort was doing in Ext 4 ?

I tried to use sorters instead,

```
{
    text: 'columnText',
    dataIndex: 'columnIndex',
    sorter: me.sort
}

sort: function(v1,v2) {
    ...
}
```

but i didn't found smth like dataIndex or columnName in v1, v2 parameters to do sort. (it's just a model)

I need empty cell be from below after Sort Ascending, empty cell be from above after Sort Descending

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem here? You can use the model object to retrieve your column data to sort. From the docs:

```
sorter: function(record1, record2) {
    var name1 = record1.data.columnIndex;
    var name2 = record2.data.columnIndex;
    return name1 > name2 ? 1 : (name1 === name2) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

EDIT: If you dont want to rewrite this for every column, then you can do a trick like this:

```
sorter: (function(columnIndex){ return function(v1, v2){ me.sort(v1, v2, columnIndex);} })("column1")
```

Now, you can get the column name as 3rd argument in your sort function.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't called when I add it to column code

Comment: If you share a simple example on fiddle, i can help.

Comment: I can do
sorter: function(v1, v2) {
      v1 = v1.data.columnIndex;
      v2 = v2.data.columnIndex;
      return v1 > v2 ? -1 : (v1 < v2 ? 1 : 0);
     }
and it will work, but I'll need to do it for each columns instead of write 1 method and call it many times

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the store, not a column. Have a look at the doSort function in ExtJS 4 for a moment:

```
doSort: function(state) {
    var tablePanel = this.up('tablepanel'),
        store = tablePanel.store;

    // If the owning Panel's store is a NodeStore, this means that we are the unlocked side
    // of a locked TreeGrid. We must use the TreeStore's sort method because we cannot
    // reorder the NodeStore - that would break the tree.
    if (tablePanel.ownerLockable && store.isNodeStore) {
        store = tablePanel.ownerLockable.lockedGrid.store;
    }
    store.sort({
        property: this.getSortParam(),
        direction: state
    });
},
/**
 * Returns the parameter to sort upon when sorting this header. By default this returns the dataIndex and will not
 * need to be overriden in most cases.
 * @return {String}
 */
getSortParam: function() {
    return this.dataIndex;
},
```

Now, this code is still working in ExtJS 6, just that it is no longer part of the framework. You can "put it back into the framework" (e.g. as an override) and it should work again. Or you can use the relevant parts directly from the column event, e.g.

```
columns:[{
    dataIndex:'ABC',
    listeners:{
        headercontextmenu:function(ct, column) {
            column.mySortState = column.mySortState=='ASC'?'DESC':'ASC';
            ct.up('grid').getStore().sort({
                property:column.dataIndex;
                direction:column.mySortState
            });
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: hi, headercontextmenu doesn't called, also as sortchange

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to define it in the model like this:

```
    fields: [{
        name: "textField",
        type: 'string',
        //sortType: 'asInt'
    }]
```